# What is the equivalent of Mathematica's RegionPlot3D[] in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to generate a 3D plot that shows the three-dimensional region representing a combination of inequalities. In Mathematica I use [`RegionPlot3D[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionPlot3D.html):

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1 && x^2 + y^2 < z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
  1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 35, PlotRange -> All]
```

which generates:

[image]

How can I do that in MATLAB?

Comment: Dear Franck, try isosurface.

Comment: @Eric thanks, I now use python from my work and don't have a Matlab license anymore but you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent function in MATLAB for `RegionPlot3D`. However, you can use `surf` to make a 3D surface plot and engineer the output mathematically. For example, your code can be rewritten in MATLAB as:

```
m=100;
n=100;

% set up the domain points
x = linspace(-1,1,m);
y = linspace(-1,1,n);

% set up the range points
z1 = nan(m,n);
z2 = nan(m,n);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        zSquared = x(i)^2+y(j)^2; % z^2
        if zSquared<=1/2
            z1(i,j) = sqrt(zSquared); % the parabola
            z2(i,j) = sqrt(1-zSquared); % the ball
        end
    end
end

AxesHandle=axes();
grid on;
hold(AxesHandle,'all');
surf(AxesHandle,x,y,z1,'EdgeColor','none'); % top part
surf(AxesHandle,x,y,z2,'EdgeColor','none');
surf(AxesHandle,x,y,-z1,'EdgeColor','none'); % bottom part
surf(AxesHandle,x,y,-z2,'EdgeColor','none');
view([-55,16]);
```

The graphics is worse than Mathematica though. Cheers.

[image: parabola && sphere]

Comment: You might want to plot the surf with `'EdgeColor','none'`

Comment: Thanks! Too bad that MATLAB doesn't have such a function. By the way, I guess you meant to add a `view(3)` at the end of your code? `'EdgeColor','none'` looks indeed nicer, thanks for the suggestion. (in my original question I had let the edge on, so I guess that's why herianto1989 they didn't remove them)

Comment: Thanks all. I've edited the post and incorporated your suggestions.